# Is it possible to put rounded corners on the first and last elements?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id='stages'>
    <div class="stage">
    stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="stage">
    more stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="stage">
    more stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to put top-rounded corners on the first "stage", and bottom-rounded corners on the last "stage". Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: Use `.stage:first-child` and `.stage:last-child` for styling first and last elements respectively.

Comment: .stages:first-child,.stages:last-child{
border-radius:25%;
}

Answer (score -2):

Use this selectors:

```
.stage:first-child
.stage:last-child
```